Understanding a simplification in a proof
While studying the book, ``Generalized function Theory and Technique Birkhauser'', specifically the section on Dirac delta function and Delta sequences, the author uses the sequence
$$s_{m}(x)=\frac{\sin(mx)}{\pi x}$$
and he claims that the following holds for $f(x)$ differentiable with $f^{\prime}(x)$
continuous and bounded

For $0<a<b$, $\lim_{m\to\infty}\int_{a}^{b} s_{m}(x)dx=0$


For $a<b<0$, $\lim_{m\to \infty}\int_{a}^{b} s_{m}(x)dx=0$

And then concludes from it that
$$\lim_{m\to\infty} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}s_{m}(x)f(x)dx=\lim_{m\to\infty}\int_{-\epsilon}^{\epsilon}s_{m}(x)f(x)dx$$
for $\epsilon$ positive and no matter how small epsilon is.
My question is how did he conclude that above line via the points (1) and (2)

Have you tried proving it yourself?

@Lorago My try:
$\lim_{m\to\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} s_{m}(x)dx=\lim_{m\to\infty}(\int_{-\infty}^{-\epsilon} s_{m}(x)dx+\int_{-\epsilon}^{\epsilon} s_{m}(x)dx\int_{\epsilon}^{\infty} s_{m}(x)dx)$ but I don't know how to continue

@Gonçalo note that the integrand in the last line is $s_{m}f(x)$ not $s_{m}(x)$, so the problem unfortunately can't be resolved by replacing your suggested values.

Did you tried splitting the integral through integration by parts in order to use the mentioned properties of $f'$?
